# Limiting number of items returned using the Notion Database API

Tags: notion-api, notion

I'm trying to get a single row from a Notion database using the API sorted by a date field.

Endpoint: `https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/DATABASEID/query`

I'm using the `filter`, `sort` and `page_size` conditions in the body request like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "property": "Last published",
    "date": {
      "is_empty": false
    }
  },
    "sorts": [
        {
            "property": "Last published",
            "direction": "ascending"
        }
    ],
    "page_size": 1
}
```

Response is a list with **all** the database entries, but I just want **one single row** as a response. Hence the `"page_size": 1` as described in the [Notion database API documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query).

What am I doing wrong here?